# what is the best way to increase diskpace for ElasticSearch cluster ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

whats is the best way to increase the disk size of prod ES cluster created in EC2 self managed. I am thinking of 2 options.
1. Add additional Data nodes.
2. Increase EBS size of each Data nodes.

Regarding 2nd option, as its prod cluster restarting nodes will affect on the cluster status. Any suggestions on this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd always prefer using local attached disks. You can read [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html#_disks) for more details.

So I'd definitely add more data nodes.